# Python converting a column in df of strings in format "%M:%S.%f" into float of number of seconds

Tags: python, pandas

I know this is a simple fix, I just cannot get it to work for the entire column. All I want to do is convert the strings in D Interval of this format %M:%S.%f to a float number of seconds.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
df["D Interval"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["D Interval"].radd("00:")).dt.total_seconds()
```

​Output :

```
print(df)
​
   Index   D Time  D Interval
0      1  00:54.3       54.30
1      2  00:57.1        2.80
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Index": [1, 2],
     "D Time": ["00:54.3", "00:57.1"],
     "D Interval": ["00:54.3", "00:02.8"]}
)
```

Comment: Nice use of `radd`!

Comment: Don't feel you have to vote for me, I like your answer that's all! (but thank you :))

Comment: No worries, I like your *re* approaches as well ;). I had to use [`radd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.radd.html) because it was the simplest one for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract`:

```
df['D Interval'] = (df['D Interval'].str.extract(r'(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+)')
                                    .astype(int).mul([60, 1, 0.1]).sum(axis=1))
print(df)

# Output
    D Time  D Interval
0  00:54.3        54.3
1  00:57.1         2.8
```

It works with `str.split` too:

```
df['D Interval'] = (df['D Interval'].str.split('[:.]', expand=True)
                                    .astype(int).mul([60, 1, 0.1]).sum(axis=1))
```